# Unity3d: WebGL video texture

Tags: javascript, video, unity-game-engine, webgl

I want to play a video in WebGL but MovieTextures re not supported. i've tried using Jonas' Simple MoTextures Sample for WebGL and it works great, but only with certain videos. I've deduced that it only works with videos that have a 2:1 aspect ratio. Such as the example one (640x320) or one I did that was 2000x1000.

If I try to use any other video I always have the same warning (hundreds of times):

> WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe
>   non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.

I am completely stuck at this point. The code is 100% the one in the sample.

BTW, in my 2000x1000 video I also get that warning, but only 5 times, and the video plays perfectly.

The code in JSlib for create and update functions:

```
 WebGLMovieTextureCreate: function(url)
{
    var str = Pointer_stringify(url);
    var video = document.createElement('video');
    video.style.display = 'none';
    video.src = str;
    return videoInstances.push(video) - 1;
},

WebGLMovieTextureUpdate: function(video, tex)
{
    if (videoInstances[video].paused)
        return;
    GLctx.bindTexture(GLctx.TEXTURE_2D, GL.textures[tex]);
    GLctx.pixelStorei(GLctx.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
    GLctx.texImage2D(GLctx.TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLctx.RGBA, GLctx.RGBA, GLctx.UNSIGNED_BYTE, videoInstances[video]);
    GLctx.pixelStorei(GLctx.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, false);
},
```

And the C# code:

```
public WebGLMovieTexture (string url)
{
    m_Instance = WebGLMovieTextureCreate(url);
    m_Texture = new Texture2D(0, 0, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
    m_Texture.wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Clamp;     
}

public void Update()
{
    var width = WebGLMovieTextureWidth(m_Instance);
    var height = WebGLMovieTextureHeight(m_Instance);
    if (width != m_Texture.width || height != m_Texture.height)
    {
        m_Texture.Resize(width, height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
        m_Texture.Apply();
    }
    WebGLMovieTextureUpdate(m_Instance, m_Texture.GetNativeTextureID());
}
```

Comment: This happens when the texture is not loaded yet. I guess the 2000x1000 file is on your local machine, thats why you get the error throwing stops earlier

Comment: But I have this error with a big video (2000x1000) but not with a smaller one (320x240) :/ And when I get the error the video never loads. Both files are from my StreamingAssets folder. Is there a way to ensure the video is loaded before rendering so I stop getting the error?

Comment: You can get rid of the error by putting 1 pixel in the texture when you create it so it's renderable immediately. My its size 1x1 when you start.

Comment: @gman do you mean from the Unity part or directly from WebGL code? I've tried changing 'new Texture2D(1,1...' but no luck. And I barely understand the WebGL part as I'm a complete noobie in WebGL. Could I get some code for that?

Comment: Ideas. Try setting 1 pixel in the texture in C#. Make sure filtering is set to texture.filterMode is Bilinear or Point in C#